# Elastic beanstalk URL changes over time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic beanstalk, will the url of ELB changes over time? Especially when the environment has been removed and start again ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The URL for your ELB (something like `awseb-e-s-AWSEBLoa-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`) will not change unless you delete it. Adding or removing web server instances will also have no effect on the load balancer's URL.

What do you mean by "when the environment has been removed and start again"? If you delete your EB application, then the associated ELB will be deleted as well.

In any case, you should not be using your ELB's URL directly. You should register a domain of your own and set up an alias that points to your ELB.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When developping an application, I need to update eb's environment config several times to compare and validate autoscaling performance. I am afraid the URL associated with ELB will change, if that so, I need to update the alias of domain again.